# I'm trying import load_weights function from utils library. Even though I have installed utils using pip but it says cannot import name load_weights

Tags: python, keras

I'm doing a project on vehicle detection
It gives the following error.

```
from utils import load_weights, Box, yolo_net_out_to_car_boxes, draw_box
```

> ImportError: cannot import name load_weights

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

This `load_weights()` function is defined in the `Model` class.

You must have a model instance and then:

```
model.load_weights('filename')
```

Comment: load_weights could be a function of the Model class, or another function in the OPs codebase. We don't know which the OP means.